# Releasedate for Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, release

Does anybody know when Rails 3 will be released?
Tried to find info on the net - but nothing useful that I found...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails 3 was released last night!!!  Let's get to work.

Answer (score 5):

I should imagine that it will be released when it's ready. There's been no release date announced that I'm aware of. Keep an eye on the [Riding Rails](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/) blog. [Ryan's Scraps](http://ryandaigle.com/) is handy for tracking Edge Rails.

Answer (score 2):

This might be interesting: http://railsnotes.com/745-rails-3-release-date-news/

Comment: What's the release date of this article? It's doesn't say on the page. I'm guessing it's 6-12 months old since it talks about Rails 3 being released in 2009

Answer (score 1):

Ruby on Rails 3 is not compatible with ruby 1.9.1 and 1.9.2-preview1. So I suppose that Ruby on Rails can't be release before the Ruby 1.9.2 release. This version is announce for August 2010. I hope Rails can be released in September 2010.

Answer (score 0):

A Rails 3 beta is available: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/2/5/rails-3-0-beta-release