# Ruby on Rails 3 Release date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a release date for Ruby on Rails 3? I've been searching but nothing yet.

Comment: Just curious ... why do you care?  Does the beta version work for you?  Is there something in the beta that you're itching to use but daren't for some reason?

Comment: Well I've been developing an application in Rails 3 Beta and it's been great util now, however I have a shared hosting account and my hosting provider "RailsPlayground" claims that they cannot install Rails 3 unless the final version is released.

Comment: When it is ready. The core team just keeps polishing it at the time being.

Comment: @juanda - you should be able to freeze the gems and deploy regardless of your host.

Comment: TBH you should use a VPS where you can have total control over your environment if you are serious about your application.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your comments, I'll def upgrade my account to VPS hosting :)

Comment: Dupe: [releasedate-for-rails-3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341614/releasedate-for-rails-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read this http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/213412#new

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3 is [currently in beta](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/2/5/rails-3-0-beta-release). Otherwise, there's no information available about a official release date.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't ask this question on the official mailing list: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/213412#927545

Comment: Really? I thought this was at least a little informative.